# Is there a way to get Lua Types from a game called ROBLOX using IDA?

Tags: lua, roblox, ida

I was wondering if I can get Lua Types { None, Nil, UserData, etc. } using IDA to achieve client sided code execution in a game called ROBLOX. If it isn't possible in IDA then is there a way I can hook to the game and retrieve those values?

I've tried serching for stuff like "**IsNil**", "**Type**", and "**Typeof**" but had no luck finding a function thats connected with a string like this to retrieve the lua type values.

Any answer will be really appricated.

**NOTE: The game itself has a very highly modified Lua VM.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tutorial Point has a decent documentation of lua. Here is the page for data types; What is an IDA? Maybe I can find the answer.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_data_types.htm

Comment: IDA is a disassembly tool for both 64bit and 32bit applications. The data types in the game change each time it updates ( weekly ) so I was wondering if I can use it to retrieve them from the game using IDA or hooking to the game itself and retrieving data types. Thanks for answering, will look more into it and mark your question as the correct one (once I figure out how to get them) if no one answers.

Comment: I am interested in your solution!

Comment: What I did was not exactly what I expected I would do, but I bought addresses because I had some of them wrong (example: pcall) , and the person who I brought the addresses from basically put what to look for in Ida ( wrap types, aobs, and data types ). For example to get the getField address you would go to view->sub views-> strings and search for "isdst" then double click the function that the string is and view its pseudo code ( decompiler plugin needed ) and you would see the address for the function there.